# Random variables question - $n$ different balls {$1, ..., n$} are placed randomly in $n$ different urns

Tags: probability, random-variables

> $n$ different balls {$1, ..., n$} are placed randomly in $n$ different urns.
>
> $X_n$ is the random variable which marks how many balls are in the "correct" (same index) urn.
>
> Using $\lim_{n \to \infty}\mathbb{P}(X_n = 0)=\frac{1}{e}$  (I already showed this in a different question), show that $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}, \lim_{n \to \infty}\mathbb{P}(X_n = k)=\frac{1}{k!e}$

My idea was to find some relation such as $\mathbb{P}(X_n = k) = \frac{1}{k!} \mathbb{P}(X_{n+k} = 0)$ using combinatorics, but I can't seem to find such a thing. Hints would be appreciated.

Comment: I assume that the balls are put uniformly and independently into the $n$ bins? Edit: Nervermind, I think you just permute the $n$ balls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability that exactly $k$ balls are in the correct urn is the sum over all length $k$ subsets of the $n$ balls of the probability of those exact $k$ balls being in the correct urn and that no other balls are in the correct urns. This is given by $$\sum \frac{1}{\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}}\mathbb{P}(X_{n-k} = 0) = \sum \frac{(n-k)!}{n!}\mathbb{P}(X_{n-k} = 0)$$

The summand will be the same no matter which of the $\binom{n}{k}$ subsets is being summed, so it simplifies to $$\binom{n}{k} \frac{(n-k)!}{n!}\mathbb{P}(X_{n-k} = 0) = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} \frac{(n-k)!}{n!} \mathbb{P}(X_{n-k} = 0) = \frac{1}{k!}\mathbb{P}(X_{n-k}=0)$$

And then you know that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P}(X_n = 0) = \frac{1}{e}$, so then $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P}(X_n = k) = \frac{1}{k!e}$$

Comment: Can you explain where $\frac{1}{\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}}$ comes from?

Comment: Nevermind I got it, thanks!